# react-native-image-picker: value returned from showImagePicker doesnt tell you if user blocked permission (Android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-permissions

I want user to select a profile picture using either camera or photo gallery.
I use react-native-image-picker to give user choice.....using below code:

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

export const _imagePickHandler = userId => {
  const options = {
    title: 'Select Profile Pic',
    takePhotoButtonTitle: 'Take photo with your camera',
    chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: 'Choose photo from library',
  };

  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, async imgPickResponse => {
    if (imgPickResponse.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (imgPickResponse.error) {
      console.log('Image Picker Error: ', imgPickResponse.error);
    } else {
      //code for success
    }
  }); 
};
```

When user click 'deny', `imgPickResponse.error` returns `Permissions weren't granted`.....and this is expected.
However the problem comes when user clicks 'deny and never ask again'.....`imgPickResponse.error` AGAIN returns `Permissions weren't granted`.  However if user has chosen this I want a different course of action.
ALSO...if I use the `check()` method from `react-native-permissions` in the callback function for `showImagePicker()` I get the same issue; regardless of whether user has 'denied' or 'denied and never ask again' I get the same response of 'denied'....it does not give me 'blocked' as Id expect.
See code below

```
export const _checkPermissions = async permission => {
  let result = await check(
    Platform.select({
      android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      ios: PERMISSIONS.IOS.PHOTO_LIBRARY,
    }),
  );
  return result;
};
```

Im using react-native-permissons version 2.1.5

Finally, here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Can you tell which version of `react-native-permissions` are you using?

Comment: Make sure you use the latest version of react-native-permissions https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions and if you still continue to have the same issue - try to create a simple app that demonstratest the problem and report it to react-native-permissions. According to their docs you should be getting a blocked response if the user selected "don't ask me again"

Comment: Im using 2.1.5.....is there a later one?

Comment: Have you tried request() instead of check() ?

Comment: Yes - its the same response for both request() and check()